# Why can't I use ActiveRecord's where method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having errors when using the where method

```
Project.where('projectid=10').first
```

It give me this :

> NoMethodError: undefined method
>   `where' for #<Class:0xb6ee1144>
>           from /home/rvb/2011/January/desaldata/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1672:in`
>   method_missing_without_paginate'
>           from /home/rvb/2011/January/desaldata/vendor/gems/mislav-will_paginate-2.3.6/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:167:in `method_missing'
>           from (irb):3

I'm using Rails 2.1.1 .. Is the where method not available in this rails version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Where' method is only available in rails 3.0.0 or above....

Comment: I see... So that makes me stick it out with the :conditions :( Do you know of any alternative to this?

Comment: you can use Project.find_all_by_id(10).first

Comment: If you want to use pre 3.0 and not use :conditions you could use raw sql as in .find_by_sql "sql here"

Comment: Why don't you want to use :conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If you do upgrade to Rails (or just ActiveRecord) 3.0, change your query to this:

```
Project.where(:projectid => 10).first
```

Also, change the name of 'projects'.'projectid', to 'projects'.'id'.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade to 3.0 yet

Comment: Ok, assuming you change the schema, your query should be Project.find(10) or Project.find(:conditions => {:id => 10})